# Angular 7 : ng test hangs , keeps running tests repeatedly

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular7

i ve recently migrated my Angular 6 app to **Angular 7**

my **package.json** looks like this :

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --public-host http://localhost:4200/",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "serve": "ng serve --optimization=true --source-map=true --eval-source-map=true --live-reload=true --aot=false --vendor-chunk=true",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5000 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --configuration=production",
    "build-localProd": "node --max_old_space_size=5000 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --configuration=localProduction",
    "build-dev": "node --max_old_space_size=7000 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --configuration=development",
    "test": "ng test --source-map=false --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "test-headless": "ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "doc": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -s --port 8081",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "sonar-scanner": "node_modules/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "2.1.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.7",
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.2.1",
    "angular-user-idle": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.2.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "devextreme": "^18.2.4",
    "devextreme-angular": "^18.2.4",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.10",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "3.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "2.1.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "1.3.5",
    "ngx-logger": "3.3.11",
    "ngx-spinner": "7.0.0",
    "popper.js": "1.14.6",
    "proxy-polyfill": "^0.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.6",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

Strangely when runnung : `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage`

The server keeps running and re-running the tests undefinitely , without stopping and without generating the **coverage** files .

this problem seems to be strange

**Sugestions ??**

Comment: Not sure whether it will help, but i've seen the repetitive running of specs behavior when code under test causes a page reload.

Comment: @TheHeadRush yeah i ve some tests cases for some methods opening new tabs ... but that should not hangs on the behaviour of the tests running

Comment: Could you share your `karma.conf.js` file -- perhaps some setting there is messing things up?

Comment: ps - sorry to see you're still including `jquery` even though you're using _Angular_.

Comment: tests that are re-ran or hanging are usually asynchronous tests on observables/promises that aren't terminated. Maybe you should check that !

Comment: @BorisYakubchik Bootstrap requires jQuery.

Answer (score 15):

Try this command `ng test -- --watch=false --code-coverage`

Comment: Adding `--watch=false` worked for me.  The output of `--help` ("`--watch 
Run build when files change.`") makes `--watch` seem like a parameterless option flag, with a default of `false` and specify it to set `true`.  But apparently the default is `true` and you have to switch it to `false` as per your answer.

Comment: @maxim palenow It used to work fine with the --watch=false flag, but the most recent Angular 13.3.11 regressed and the process will not exit even after the tests are done. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: @CupidChan I've checked on 13.3.11 and npx ng test -- --watch=false or npm run ng test -- --watch=false work for me. The process exits after tests completion.

Check async tests, maybe you unresolved promise framework is waiting and a high timeout.

Comment: @MaximPalenov I found out that the problem is due to I am in the middle of upgrading to Angular 14. The test hangs if I haven't upgrade the whole platform AND test framework. However, it works again AFTER I upgrade both.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and what I discovered was that in Angular 7 they changed that when you run `ng test` without specifying a specific project it runs tests for all the projects you have inside your `angular.json` workspace file and not just the main application. Then it looks like it goes on indefinitely or there is a bug and it cycles the projects.

Try to run `ng test <projectname>` and see if you still get the same. For me this solved the issue.

Here is also a link to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/cli/test#ng-test) that explains it in the description of the command.