# Angular: How to Unit Test Public Members which are Only used as Input in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular8

Angular `ng test --code-coverage` is asking me to Unit Test Public variables. The variables are strictly used as Direct Input in html. How can this be unit tested?

[image]

Variables get placed into other Input area components:

```
<ctrl-grid 
  [gridData]="agencyAssociatedList" 
  [pageSizes]="pageSizes" 
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [(state)]="gridState"
  [buttonCount]="buttonCount"
  [previousNext]="previousNext"
  [loadDataWithState]="exportData"
  >
```

Comment: Hey @marksmith527. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Can you please confirm if you turned on sourceMap or not ?

Comment: Generally, these sort of issues come up when sourceMap is turned off

Comment: Actually, sourceMap reduces the testing speed. So, we generally turn off for better speed mainly while preparing the boiler plate for tests

Comment: can you please try ..

ng test --sourceMap=true --code-coverage=true ?

Comment: we use this, ng test --source-map=false --code-coverage

Comment: See.. you are turning sourceMap off, please try ng test --sourceMap=true --code-coverage=true

Comment: we had this prior issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482449/angular-7-ng-test-hangs-keeps-running-tests-repeatedly    https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5423

Comment: Whether the variables are now covered after turning sourceMap on ?

Comment: You can add --watch=false for that issue :)

Comment: hi, @Akhil you can write in answer, and I can send points, can you cite resource for this? "Sourcemap is turned off causes non code coverage for public variables?" that's interesting

Comment: Does my below answer makes sense ? @AlanSmith5482

Answer (score 0):

You will need to turn on sourceMaps to enable full coverage of the code.

So, what is sourceMap ?

> A source map is a JSON file that contains all the necessary information to map the transpiled code back to the original sources

Since Angular transpiles TS to JS, when sourceMaps are enabled then it can map the actual TS code block which is getting covered in transpiled JS.

Not only public variables but sometimes branches are also not covered completely when sourceMap is turned off.